# Prove that a function defines a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

> Prove that the function $d:\mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}$ defined by the following way is a metric on $
>  \mathbb{R}^{2}$: If $x = y$, define $d\left ( x,y \right )=0$. If $x
>  \neq y$, then the points $x,y$ determine a line in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
>   If this line passes through the origin of a rectangular coordinate
>   system, we put $d\left ( x,y \right )=d_{0}\left ( x,y \right )$,
>   otherwise we put $d\left ( x,y \right )=d_{0}\left ( x,0 \right
>   )+d_{0}\left ( 0,y \right )$.

Here, $d_{0}$ is the Euclidian metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and o is the origin of the coordinate system. Furthermore, $x=\left [ x_{1}, x_{2} \right ]$, $y=\left [ y_{1}, y_{2} \right ]$ and $o=\left [ 0, 0 \right ]$.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That $d$ is a metric follows more or less easy from the definition of $d$ and the fact that $d_0$ is a metric.

Comment: @Jan my problem is that I have to show it, following the three properties defining the metric space

Comment: @Jan Can you show me, how it follows from the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $d(x, y) = 0$. Then, by definition of $d$, this is equivalent to $x = y$.

Now we want to verify $d(x, y) \geq 0$. This is clear if $x = y$ (since then we have $d(x, y) = 0$), so assume $x \neq y$.

- Suppose first that the line determined by $x$ and $y$ passes through
  the origin. Then $d(x, y) = d_0(x, y) \geq 0$. Note that $d_0(x, y)
     \geq 0$ since $d_0$ is a metric.
- Now suppose that the line does not pass through the origin. Then
  $d(x, y) = d_0(x, 0) + d_0(0, y) \geq 0 + 0 = 0$ by a similar
  argument. Thus, $d(x, y) \geq 0$.

We now show symmetry. This is clear for $x = y$, so assume $x \neq y$.

- If the line passes through $o$, then $d(x, y) = d_0(x, y) = d_0(y, x)
     = d(y, x)$. Note that the second equality again follows from the fact that $d_0$ is metric.
- If the line does not pass through the origin, then we have \begin{align} d(x, y) &=
     d_0(x, 0) + d_0(0, y) \\
  &= d_0(0, x) + d_0(y, 0) \\
  &= d_0(y, 0) + d_0(0, x) \\
     &= d(y, x).\end{align} Hence, $d$ is symmetric.

We finally have to check the triangle inequality. Take $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and assume $x = y$. Then $d(x, y) = 0 \leq d(x, z) + d(z, y)$ is always true, since we have $d \geq 0$. Suppose now $x \neq y$.

- If the line passes through the origin, then we have \begin{align} d(x, y) &= d_0(x, y) \\
     &\leq d_0(x, z) + d_0(z, y) \\
  &= d(x, z) + d_0(z, y),\end{align} since $d_0$ is a
  metric.
- Finally, assume that the line does not pass through the origin. Then
  \begin{align} d(x, y) &= d_0(x, 0) + d_0(0, y) \\
  &\leq d_0(x, 0) + d_0(0, z) + d_0(z,
     0) + d_0(0, y) \\
  &= d(x, z) + d(z, y). \end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome.